# WPF MessageBox Default To Cancel

Tags: wpf, messagebox

With this the default is OK.  Can I make the default Cancel?

```
   MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show
      (message, caption, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598695.aspx), which allows you to specify the default [`MessageBoxResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messageboxresult.aspx):

```
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show
    (message, caption, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel,  
        MessageBoxImage.Information, MessageBoxResult.Cancel);
```